# O bloco finally é sempre executado em Java?

Tags: java, try-finally

Neste código há um bloco de *try/catch* com um *return* dentro dele.

```
try {  
    alguma_coisa();  
    return successo;  
}  
catch (Exception e) {   
    return falha;  
}  
finally {  
    System.out.println("Eu não sei se será possível printar esta mensagem");
}
```

Rodar este código seria simples, porém a idéia da pergunta é:

Não somente nesta ocasião, mas, o bloco *finally* sempre será chamado em Java?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O bloco `finally` **sempre será executado, salvo em raras situações.**

De forma geral ele é a garantia de que seu código irá liberar recursos ocupados mesmo que ocorram exceções (`Exceptions`) ou o método contendo o `try` retorne prematuramente (`return`).

Os únicos momentos em que o `finally` não será chamado são:

1. Se você chamar `System.exit()` ou
2. um outro *thread* interromper o atual (através do método `interrupt()`) ou
3. Se a JVM der *crash* antes.

Conforme os [tutoriais da Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed,
>   then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread
>   executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally
>   block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

*(Resposta baseada em [pergunta 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java) e [pergunta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run) do StackOverflow em inglês).*

Answer (score 7):

#### Sim, ele sempre será executado!

O bloco `finally` é utilizado para garantir que um código seja executado após um `try`, **mesmo que uma exceção tenha sido gerada**. **Mesmo que tenha um return** no `try` ou no `catch`, **o bloco finally é sempre executado**.

#### Por qual motivo isso acontece?

O bloco `finally`, geralmente, é utilizado para fechar conexões, arquivos e liberar recursos utilizados dentro do bloco `try/catch`. Como ele é sempre executado, nós conseguimos garantir que sempre após um recurso ser utilizado dentro do `try/catch` ele poderá ser fechado/liberado no `finally`.

Answer (score 5):

Sim. O bloco Finally sempre será executado mesmo se cair no catch.

Faça esse teste:

```
    public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    try {  
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int res = a/b;
        System.out.println(res);
    }  
    catch (Exception e) {   
        System.out.println("Erro.");  
    }  
    finally {  
        System.out.println("Finally");
    }

    }

    }
```

Note que esse algoritimo irá gerar uma exception pois não é possível efetuar a divisão de 0 por 0.
Então ele vai gerar uma exception e cair no bloco do finally.
Espero ter ajudado, abraços.