# Para que serve "ensure" em Ruby? Dê um Exemplo

Tags: ruby

Para que serve "ensure" em Ruby? Dê um Exemplo prático em que situações ele é útil.

Estou estudando esse site aqui: tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm Mas ele não esta bem claro sobre 'ensure' em exceptions. Seria como o finally do Python?

Comment: Isso parece ser um enunciado de exercício. Se for, como acha que é a resposta? Como você descreveria a função do `ensure`?

Comment: Estou estudando esse site aqui: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm 
Mas ele não esta bem claro sobre 'ensure' em exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `ensure` do Ruby é equivalente ao `finally` de outras linguagens: ele define um bloco de código que sempre será executado, seja após o bloco em `begin`, seja após a captura de uma exceção.

```
begin
    puts 'Bloco de código que será tentado executar'
    raise 'Algo errado não está certo'
rescue Exception
    puts 'É, algo saiu errado'
ensure
    puts 'Esse trecho sempre será executado'
end
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GrownFeminineParallelalgorithm)</sup>

A saída seria:

```
Bloco de código que será tentado executar
É, algo saiu errado
Esse trecho sempre será executado
```

Se não houvesse o `raise` dentro do bloco em `begin`, o bloco em `rescue` não seria executado, apenas o `ensure`:

```
begin
    puts 'Bloco de código que será tentado executar'
rescue Exception
    puts 'É, algo saiu errado'
ensure
    puts 'Esse trecho sempre será executado'
end
```

Produzindo a saída:

```
Bloco de código que será tentado executar
Esse trecho sempre será executado
```

É uma ferramenta útil quando você precisa garantir (daí o nome `ensure`, garantir em inglês) que um determinado trecho de código seja executado ocorrendo alguma falha ou não. Um exemplo hipotético seria, por exemplo, no gerenciamento da comunicação com o banco de dados e transações:

```
begin
    db = Database.new
    db.connect
    db.transaction.start
    db.persist(entity)
    db.transaction.commit
rescue Exception
    db.transaction.rollback
ensure
    db.close
end
```

Assim, falhando ou não a persistência dos dados no banco, a conexão seria devidamente fechada.

Outras leituras:

- [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58536/5878)
- [Como e quando usar o Finally após um Try?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16065/5878)
- [Uso específico do try-catch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108484/5878)
- [O bloco finally é sempre executado em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82333/5878)
- [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13303/5878)
- [Pra que serve o finally no PHP 5.5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48279/5878)

Comment: Já desconfiava. Muito obrigado por esclarecer suficiente minha dúvida.